# What is wrong with the logic in my program?

Tags: c++, arrays

I've been tasked to create a function that identifies the number of occurrences in an array, however i am not getting the correct result. This is the function i wrote, i left out the rest of the program as that works.

```
int countOccurences(int b[], int size, int x)
{
    int occ = x;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
            if(b[i] == occ)
            occ++;

    }
    cout << occ << endl;

    return occ;
}
```

Comment: `int occ = 0;`, `if(b[i] == x)`, apples and oranges, you're mixing them.

Comment: Why are you not using `std::array`

Comment: Might I suggest not bothering to write such a function and just use the standard [std::count](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) instead. No point in reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! Well I'm honestly not sure what std: : array is. Every time b[i] is equal to x, occ will increase by 1? Just trying to understand the code so it makes sense to me.

Comment: How you wrote the function without knowing what you're doing interests me.

Comment: I haven't learned any of that, i'm in a level 1 c++ course, and to be honest the assignments all perform unnecessary tasks, and are quite difficult compared to the learning material

Comment: i use the given material and previous assignments as reference, i am able to understand the code, but coming up with it is sometimes beyond me, its only been about a month and a half and i'm hoping it takes longer than that to be a good programmer

Answer (score 1):

If `occ` is meant to be the number of occurrences, it should be initialised to zero rather than `x`.

And the comparison should be between `b[i]` and `x`, not `b[i]` and `occ`.

---

And, as an aside (not affecting your actual logic), it's also very unusual to actually print out the return value in a utility function which is obviously meant to simply *return* the count but it may be you have that in there just for debug purposes.

And you should both ensure your indentation and use of braces is consistent between your `for` and your `if` - it will make your code easier to maintain.

That's all totally aside from the fact that C++ possesses a `std::count()` method in `<algorithm>` that will work this out for you *without* having to write a function to do it (although it may be that this is an educational question and the intent is to learn how to code things like this, rather than use readily made library functions to do the heavy lifting for you).

Comment: yeah i had that cout for debugging, i have removed it now though.

Answer (score 0):

```
int countOccurences(int b[], const unsigned int size, const int x)
{
    int occ = 0;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
            if(b[i] == x)
            {
                occ++;
            }
    }
    std::cout << occ << std::endl;

    return occ;
}
```

- `occ` should start at zero
- You should compare `b[i]` to `x`
- Array indices should be unsigned
- Why not be const-correct?
- `using namespace std;` is bad practice

Comment: Here, let me fix that for you: "`using namespace std;` is bad practice in any substantially complicated code, of which this is probably not" :-) On a more serious note, it would have been better to state *why* it's bad practice, even if it was only a short precis, something like "`using namespace std;` is considered bad practice in non-trivial code, as it can lead to clashes between namespaces".